# PHP - Extract Line by line in Sprintf output

Tags: php

I have a CSV file, that I am using to populate a table - that works fine.  The table is an inquiry form, so users can select the item(s) they want more information on and submit an email.

In this email I need to include the item details.  So far I am only able to get the value of "1" field within the row to submit.

In my searches I found a way to get the needed fields from the rows into a line, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get each line individually to use as the value of the check box.

Here is my code:

```
$file = fopen('myfile.csv', 'r'); 
$fields = array(); 

if ($file) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    if(empty($fields)) {
        $fields = $data;
        continue;
    }

    $row = array_combine($fields, $data);

    $output = sprintf("%s - %s - %u <br />\n",
$row['make'],
$row['model'],
$row['serial']);      

    echo $output;
}
fclose($file);
}
```

This creates a list like ...

```
Tanglewood - TW66 - 311592807

MICHAEL KELLY - MKDF4FL - 311595895

Epiphone - DR500MCE - 311599764

ALVAREZ - MD70CE - 311603486

FENDER - *CD220SCE ASH BURL - 311606198
```

Which is perfect ... but in the table I have the check box to select for inquiry.  That check box needs to have the value of that line only, so I need to count the number of rows, and then grab 1 line for whichever number row we are on.

Something like `echo $output[3];` would give me 
`Epiphone - DR500MCE - 311599764`

**EDIT ---**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
    <table class="tablesaw" data-tablesaw-sortable data-tablesaw-sortable-switch>
        <thead>
            <tr>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2"></th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="persist">Make</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Model</th>

                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Serial</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">RPD</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Retail</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="5">Net Price</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="6">Photo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<?php
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
$fields = array();
if($file)
{
while(($data=fgetcsv($file, ',')) !== false)
 {
  if(empty($fields))
 {
  $fields = $data;
 continue;
}
 $row = array_combine($fields, $data);
 $output[] = sprintf("%s - %s - %u <br />\n", $row['make'], $row['model'], $row['serial']);
}
 fclose($file);

}

 for($x=0; $x < count($output); $x++)
  {
// Build lines of checkbox rows here
echo($output[$x]);
}
?>


<?php 
$f = fopen("file.csv", "r");


$columns1 = array(1);
$columns2 = array(2,3,4,5,6);
$columns3 = array(7);


$flag = true;



while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $index=>$val) {


if (in_array($index+1, $columns1)) {
echo("\t<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='$val'></td>\r\n");
}


if (in_array($index+1, $columns1)) {
echo("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n");
}


if (in_array($index+1, $columns2)) {
echo("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n");
}

if (in_array($index+1, $columns3)) {

if($val == "0"){
    echo("\t<td></td>\r\n");
} else {
     echo("\t<td><a class=' wpex-lightbox' href='http://mirc.pixelcraftstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/mirc_inv_pics/$val.jpg' target='_self' data-type='image'><img style='width:24px; height:24px; margin-top:8px;' src='http://mirc.pixelcraftstudio.net/wp-content/themes/mirc-child/tablesaw/icon-instagram.jpg'/></a></td>\r\n");
    }
            }

    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
?>

        </tbody>
    </table>

<input style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:50%; font-size:16px; margin- left:-155px;" name="submit" type="submit" value="Contact Us About Your     Selected Items" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create an array, currently your code doesn't do this.  Try changing this line:

```
$output = sprintf("%s - %s - %u <br />\n", $row['make'], $row['model'], $row['serial']);
```

to:

```
$output[] = sprintf("%s - %s - %u <br />\n",$row['make'], $row['model'], $row['serial']);
```

Now:
`echo $output[3];`, etc should contain your data.

You may have to build the array like this instead:

```
$output[] = array("make"=>"$row['make']", "model"=>"$row['model']", "serial"=>"$row['serial']");
```

Now:
`echo $output[3]['make'];`, etc should contain your 'make' data, repeat for each array element ('model' and 'serial').

**EDIT - New Code**

I did not address your table building needs.  All I did was get the data into the format you requested.  I had several problems with your original code, it did not run as you posted it.  $fields contained 7 elements while $data contained 6 elements.  For this reason array_combine() failed.  I had to add 'null' to the last element of the csv file.  I loaded your sample data into Excel and created a csv file from it.  Also, the keys are case sensitive, so $row['make'] had to became $row['Make'], .... etc.  Arrays are 0 based so `echo($output[2])` will output `Epiphone - DR500MCE - 311599764`.  I hope this meets your needs.

```
$file = fopen('inventory.csv', 'r');
$fields = array();
if($file)
{
 while(($data=fgetcsv($file, ',')) !== false)
 {
  if(empty($fields))
  {
   $fields = $data;
   continue;
  }
  $row = array_combine($fields, $data);
  $output[] = sprintf("%s - %s - %u <br />\n", $row['Make'], $row['Model'], $row['Serial']);
 }
 fclose($file);
 foreach($output as $key=>$value)
 {
  // Build lines of checkbox rows here
  echo($key . ': '. $value);
 }
}
```

**Edit - Addition**

That's easy, use a for loop instead of a foreach loop, like this:

```
 for($x=0; $x < count($output); $x++)
 {
  // Build lines of checkbox rows here
  echo($output[$x]);
 }
```

This way you can also change the id attribute of each checkbox by adding the number value to the id.

**EDIT - Last**

This is a complete web page, it builds the table as the csv page you posted before and it puts the value you wanted in the checkbox.  The only thing you should do to make life simple is update your Excel file to include the Photo path/name.  BE SURE to include the opening and closing img tags in that field and you should be good to go.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Table</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
 <table class="tablesaw" data-tablesaw-sortable data-tablesaw-sortable-switch>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Select</th>
    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="persist">Make</th>
    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Model</th>
    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Serial</th>
    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">RPD</th>
    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Retail</th>
    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="5">Net Price</th>
    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="6">Photo</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
$file = fopen('inventory.csv', 'r');
$fields = array();
if($file)
{
 while(($data=fgetcsv($file, ',')) !== false)
 {
  if(empty($fields))
  {
   $fields = $data;
   continue;
  }
  $output[] = array_combine($fields, $data);
 }
 fclose($file);
 foreach($output as $main)
 {
  echo('   <tr>' . PHP_EOL);
  echo("    <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]'  value='{$main['Make']} - {$main['Model']} - {$main['Serial']}'></td>");
  foreach($main as $key=>$value)
  {
   echo("<td>$value</td>");
  }
  echo(PHP_EOL . '   </tr>' . PHP_EOL);
 }
}
?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <br>
 <input style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 50%; font-size: 16px; margin-left: -155px;" name="submit" type="submit" value="Contact Us About Your Selected Items">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Fabio Cardoso, thanks for formatting my answer.  I'm still trying to figure SO out.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of those throw errors.  The first option displays
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in ... then shows the 4th row repeatedly over and over.

The second option shows error "syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)"

Comment: Maybe it might help to show how I populate the table -

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the actual CSV file as well?

Comment: The reason I asked for sample CSV data is because I'm confused.  Your first posted code shows you reading the file, building an associative array for that line of data, until you reach the end of file, then you close the file.  Your 2nd posted code does not follow that logic.  And it shows you using the variable $columns4 but I don't see that defined anywhere in your code.  In order to use my suggestions you need to read the file, build the array and then close the file before you start building your table.  Anyway, show me some sample data and I'll see what I come up with.

Comment: Yes I can see how it may be confusing ... Im confused as well.  The second block of code is what I use for the table.

The actual end result I am looking for is to just get the 3 columns of desired data into the checkbox value.

http://mirc.pixelcraftstudio.net/dealers-only/inventory/

That is the table - csv file is basically the same.  Select as many checkboxes as you want and hit the blue button fixed at the bottom of the page.  It shows you selected the items and lists the makes.  I need Make, Model and Serial in this step of the process.

Comment: $index+3, $columns4 should be
$index+1, $columns1 ... what I posted before was left from another try at something to get this working, sorry.

Comment: I need to see how the actual data is formatted.  Is it comma or tab delimited?  Do you double quote any/all fields?  Anyway, I've never used sprintf to build an array so maybe that is what is causing the error you mentioned.  But, the 2nd code example is valid so I don't understand why it is giving you an error.  Maybe you need to put curly braces around the variables, like this:    $output[] = array("make"=>"{$row['make']}", "model"=>"{$row['model']}", "serial"=>"{$row['serial']}");.  Try it with your 1st posted code example.

Comment: @Ben - I have updated the code, please see my edited answer above.

Comment: Sweet!.  I havent tested this, but it makes sense and should work.  Thank you.  Now my next question ... 

My checkboxes are created dynamically for each.  How can I take that code above, and add "1" each time it is used.

echo($output[2]) - ADD ONE - so next will be echo($output[3]), etc, etc in my table?

Comment: Please see my code addition above.  Also, if this answer meets your needs please mark it as such.

Comment: Okay - getting there.  I edited my initial post to show the full form code.  The top is the new code you gave me - bottom is the table. 

Your new loop you provided works great - but how do I use it in the checkbox value?

I usually have a pretty good handle on this stuff - lurking around here for years, but this is just slamming me against the wall ... your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before I give you another answer let me ask you a question.  Are you trying to build a table just like the sample csv page you posted?  Showing all 6 columns + 1 for the photo?  And you want the value of $output[$x] to be the name value?  Where will the photo href url come from?

Comment: The csv file is
http://mirc.pixelcraftstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/mirc_inventory/inventory.csv

Website is
http://mirc.pixelcraftstudio.net/dealers-only/inventory/

Top is the "for" loop you gave me.  Bottom is the actual table.

Everything works perfect except the checkbox.  I can only get it to use "1" item as the value (currently the make).  I need the value of the checkbox to show make, model and serial for "that" row of the selected checkbox.

Photos are the id names of the images - they will upload.  csv will say 32456 (image will be 32456.jpg)  No worries on that.

Comment: Okay, check out the new code I posted above.  Be sure to change the csv file name.

Comment: Thanks - Works Great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code Im using to generate the table.

```
<?php 
$f = fopen("file.csv", "r");


$columns1 = array(1);
$columns2 = array(2,3,4,5,6);
$columns3 = array(7);


$flag = true;

while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $index=>$val) {

if (in_array($index+1, $columns1)) {
echo("\t<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='$val'>    </td>\r\n");
}


if (in_array($index+1, $columns1)) {
echo("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n");
}

if (in_array($index+1, $columns2)) {
echo("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n");
}

if (in_array($index+1, $columns3)) {

if($val == "0"){
    echo("\t<td></td>\r\n");
} else {
     echo("\t<td><a class=' wpex-lightbox' href='http://mirc.pixelcraftstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/mirc_inv_pics/$val.jpg' target='_self' data-type='image'><img style='width:24px; height:24px; margin-top:8px;' src='http://mirc.pixelcraftstudio.net/wp-content/themes/mirc-child/tablesaw/icon-instagram.jpg'/></a></td>\r\n");
    }
            }

    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

So the first column I have the checkbox, and can get that tho show the value of the first column.  But I need the value for columns 1,2 and 3 to be included in the checkbox.

Maybe my method of thinking with getting the 3 items first is not the best approach?

The 7th column is only split because its an image and needs a preview icon